# Moving from Heroku to Rackspace Cloud Server: few questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rackspace-cloud, rackspace

I'm considering migrating from Heroku to Rackspace Cloud Server, but I have few questions.

1. First, did anyone of you moved from heroku to rcd and, in your opinion, did you do the right choice?
2. what is the equivalent of web-dynos in a cloud server ?
3. How do I handle background jobs (resque) effectively.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are essentially different things.

Rackspace Cloud Servers are similar to Amazon's EC2. They are *virtual servers* you have root access to. Nothing more. It's a concept known as [Infrastructure as a Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_as_a_service#Infrastructure)

What this means is that, once your server is up and running, you have to install all the software you need to run your app: web servers, databases, application servers etc...
These chores can certainly be automated, but someone from your team still has to do that.

Heroku on the other hand is a [Platform as a Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service) - You don't have to bother installing any software. They provide a complete solution stack where you can deploy your app to. You literally just need to put your code there.

What's best? That depends. I certainly don't want to have to deal with installing the software myself unless I absolutely had to. That way I can focus most of my time actually developing my product.

Sorry I didn't answer your three questions but it's hard to do so given they are two very distinct solutions.